# send variables to server

Tags: php, html

I have a link on my page that may have an error in it. I don't know the url to this page but when a user clicks this link I want the same page to refresh and pass these variables for processing. My link here seems to work but 
my concern is:

when I view the page and open up page source I get the '&' highlighted in red which to me means that there is some sort of error. Is this line compliant to the web standards?

```
 <a name="anchorOpen" href="?folder=<?php echo $j; ?>&full=<?php echo 

 $fullScreen;?>#anchorOpen" > <img  src="<?php print "$firstPic[$j]";?>" 

  class="folderPic"/></a>
```

is this the way to combine vars passed through a link. Is there anything wrong with this line? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ampersands (`&` symbols) should be written as `&amp;` in HTML. This is because `&` symbols are in a list of reserved symbols. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) as a reference.

There's also the option to use the php `htmlentities()` function if you wanted to echo the whole lot as a php string.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the & is showed in red makes me think that the & is not within quotes (").
If you are passing a variable into an url you could consider using *urlencode()*

```
<?php
     echo '<a name="anchorOpen" href="?folder='.urlencode($j).'&full='.urlencode($fullScreen).'#anchorOpen">';
     echo '<img  src="'.urlencode($firstPic[$j]).'" class="folderPic"/></a>';
?>
```

Comment: Im just making sure. I thought I needed the '&' to join the strings. That is what  '&' does right?

Answer (score 0):

The most correct way is to use `urlencode()` for variables you inject in URLs.
Say, "`foo bar`" will be converted to "`foo+bar`"
Or, "`foo&bar`" will totally break the URL, so it will be converted to "`foo%26bar`"

So, in your example it would be:

```
<a href="?folder=<?php echo urlencode($j)?>&full=<?php echo urlencode($fullscreen)?>#anchorOpen"><img  src="<?php echo $firstPic[$j]?>" class="folderPic"/></a>
```

Then, in PHP script, no need to do anything special - the $_GET variables will be auto-converted back, so you'll have "`foo bar`" and "`foo&bar`" exactly as they were before.